# Loading 30MB XML to autocomplete

Tags: java, android, xml, autocompletetextview

I have a 30 MB XML with thousands of words.

What would be the best way to use it with autocomplete.

I can load the whole xml in to an array.
Or i can create a DB in the cloud and use RestAPI for getting the words.

What will be the best way?
Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why dont u add them to a database and search within? BTW, how many thousands?

Comment: about 90,000. i'm trying to cut the list down by half. but still a lot of words

Answer (score -3):

Youn can try to using **ElasticSearch** to your project

Comment: what is `Elastic Serach`

Comment: I need to load my XML to autocomplete. not a search engine.

Comment: elasticsearch.org. Elasticsearch is a search engine